# Creating two dimensional array of class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Hi if anybody could advise how to correctly do this. Basically I'm trying to make a class variable called Board who holds in it a two dimensional array of ChessPiece instances.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class ChessPiece
{
public:
    char ToChar() { return '#'; };
};

class ChessBoard
{
    int Size;   //This means board is 8x8.
    ChessPiece ** Board;

public:
    ChessBoard();
    int GetSize() { return Size; };

    void PlotBoard();
};

ChessBoard::ChessBoard() {
    Size = 8;
    ChessPiece newBoard[Size][Size];
    Board = newBoard; //Problem here!!! How do I make Board an 8x8 array of ChessPiece?
}

void ChessBoard::PlotBoard() {
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < Size; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < Size; y++)
            printf("%c", Board[x][y].ToChar());
    }
}

int main()
{
    // ChessBoard board;
    // printf("%d", board.GetSize());
    // board.PlotBoard();

    ChessBoard * a = new ChessBoard();

    return 0;
}
```

Pretty basic thing I'm missing here really, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Thank you!

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece>>`, or even more simply `std::vector<ChessPiece>` and track the index as row/column using simple multiplication.

Comment: I'd do it exactly like @Chad. I myself would use the second version, but that's not important.

Comment: Does the program need to support only the standard 8x8 chess board, or do you want to be able to play on arbitrary-sized chessboards other than 8x8 as well?  If you only need the standard 8x8, you might as well make Size a constant and then just use a simple 8x8 fixed-size two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no reason to use raw pointers in your scenario.  I'd suggest holding the board as a single dimensional `std::vector`, and simply use multiplication to of the row/column when iterating the board.

```
class ChessBoard
{
public:
   ChessBoard(size_t row_count) : Size(row_count), Board(row_count * row_count)
   {
   }

   void PlotBoard()
   {
     for(size_t row = 0; row < Size; ++row)
     {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < Size; ++col)
            printf("%c", Board[(row * Size) + col].ToChar());
     }
   }
}

private:
   size_t Size;
   std::vector<ChessPiece> Board;
};
```

Comment: You certainly meant `Board[row * Size + col]`, didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor to:

```
ChessBoard::ChessBoard():Size(8) {
    Board=new ChessPiece*[Size];

    for (int i=0;i<Size;++i)
        Board[i]=new ChessPiece[Size];
}
```

You will also need a destructor:

```
ChessBoard::~ChessBoard()
{
    for (int i=0;i<Size;++i)
        delete [] Board[i];

    delete [] Board;
}
```

If you want to allow for copying/moving, be sure to add a proper copy/move constructor and copy/move assignment operator(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
class ChessBoard {
    public:
    enum Field {
       Empty,
       Pawn,
       ...
    };
    const Columns = 8;
    const Rows = 8;
    Field& operator()(unsigned column, unsigned row) { 
        return fields(column * Rows + row);
    } // omitting const/non const and range checks

    private:
    Field fields[Columns * Rows];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar type of project last year. For it I created a Square class, so that a Board would be made up of a 2-D array of Squares. I think this way you have more flexibility in that you can then create methods for Square like checking if there is a Piece (class of its own) on the Square, what type of Piece and adding and removing Pieces.

I think you need to come at the problem in a basic OO manner.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that newBoard is being created with automatic storage duration, which means it will be wiped out when you go out of scope (at the end of the ChessBoard constructor).  If Size will never change you can set it to a constant and create the board like this:

```
#define SIZE 8
class ChessBoard
{
    ChessPiece Board[SIZE][SIZE];
```

If Size might change you'll need to allocate the arrays in a loop like this:

```
Board = new ChessPiece *[Size];
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
    Board[i] = new ChessPiece[Size];
}
```

Comment: -1: using `new` is counter-productive and error prone. (consider `std::vector`, already recommended in another answer) Also, you don't mention in your answer how to deallocate memory.